# Typeof/instanceof type alias

Tags: typescript

I wonder if it is possible to determine the type of an object in typescript. Please consider the example below:

```
type T = [number, boolean];

class B {
    foo: T = [3, true];

    bar(): boolean {
        return this.foo instanceof T;
    }
}
```

The typeof operator does not seem to be a solution, neither does instanceof.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer**

(Almost) all type information are removed after compilation, and you can't use `instanceof` operator with an operand (`T` in your example) that **does not exist at runtime**.

**Long answer**

An identifier in TypeScript could belong to one or more of the following groups: *type*, *value*, *namespace*. What gets emitted as JavaScript is identifiers in the group of *value*.

Thus runtime operators only works with *values*. So if you want to do runtime type checking of the value of `foo`, you'll need to do the hard work yourself.

See the [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) section of the TypeScript Handbook for more information.

Answer (score 6):

To add to **@vilcvane**'s answer: `types` and `interfaces` disappear during compilation, but some `class` information is still available.  So, for example, this doesn't work:

```
interface MyInterface { }

var myVar: MyInterface = { };

// compiler error: Cannot find name 'MyInterface'
console.log(myVar instanceof MyInterface);
```

But this does:

```
class MyClass { }

var myVar: MyClass = new MyClass();

// this will log "true"
console.log(myVar instanceof MyClass);
```

However, it's important to note that this kind of test can be misleading, even when your code compiles with no errors:

```
class MyClass { }

var myVar: MyClass = { };

// no compiler errors, but this logs "false"
console.log(myVar instanceof MyClass);
```

[This makes sense if you look at how TypeScript is generating the output JavaScript in each of these examples](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Avar%20myVar%3A%20MyClass%20%3D%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0A%0Adocument.writeln((myVar%20instanceof%20MyClass).toString())%3B).

Comment: The class is still there because a class belongs to *value* and *type* group the same time. In the second example, another key is that TypeScript do type checking based on the "shape" of types. Though there are discussions about nominal types on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***user-defined type guard*** for that.
See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) article for more details.

As for your code, here is the function you can define to check if your object is a `T`:

```
  type T = [number, boolean];
  
  const isT = (value: any): value is T =>
    Array.isArray(value) &&
    typeof value[0] === 'number' &&
    typeof value[1] === 'boolean';
```

Then use it this way:

```
const foo = [3, true];
console.log(isT(foo)); // true
const bar = 3;
console.log(isT(bar)); // false
```

Here is a simple [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-385tsm?file=index.ts) to demonstrate this.