# Convert type back to value

Tags: tsc, typescript3.0

I am converting a class to a type, but I want to convert that type back to a class. Say I have this class:

```
export namespace Entities{
  export namespace Bar{
    export class Foo {

    }
  }
}
```

and then I have a reference to the type:

```
type F = Entities.Bar.Foo;
```

is there a way to convert F back to a value instead a type?

something like:

```
const V = valueof F;
```

where V would just be a reference to the Foo class.

(I guess what is weird is that a class in TypeScript is both a type and a value/expression).

The *reason I ask* is because I have this scenario:

```
type F = Entities.Bar.Foo;
const x = doSomethingWithClass(Entities.Bar.Foo);
```

but I would like to convert it to this scenario:

```
type F = Entities.Bar.Foo;
doSomethingWithClass(F);
```

but that doesn't compile, I get:

> Can't use type F as an expression.

**alternatively**, if someone knows how to return a type from a function, that might be good enough:

```
type F = doSomethingWithClass(Entities.Bar.Foo);
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. `const x = typeof Foo` would give you a reference to the `Foo` class.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen let me update the question to make it more clear

Comment: Updated, basically,  I can only access Foo, by referring to the full namespace path, but I am trying to store a temp reference to the type, so I don't have to keep referring to the full namespace path.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35745895/3558960) relevant?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I added a "reason I ask" section to the OP, does what I am asking make sense? I followed your link but I don't think it helps (but maybe I am mistaken).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if the OP is not clear here, so this issue on Github for different language https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28872